# Using rooms with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

In the `socket.io` documentation I see an example of rooms

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('say to someone', function(id, msg){
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg);
  });
});
```

I have a route `/rooms/:roomId`.

Is it possible to make the sockets being sent between the server and the client only hits the specific room?

I guess the server should be something like

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('new msg from client', function(roomId, msg){
    io.to(id).emit('new msg from server', msg);
  });
});
```

above and the client should send messages with

```
socket.emit('new msg from client', roomId, msg);
```

and get new messages simply with

```
socket.on('new msg from server', function () {
  document.getElementById('msgs').appendChild(...);
});
```

But will this work? Shouldn't I join the room with `socket.join(...)` before I can do this?

Comment: Yeah, a socket needs to join a room and then it will be privy to all the messages that go to that "room."  However, you can keep a list of clientIDs in an array and directly iterate through a list.  Rooms is a cool idea, but there are different ways to achieve the same effect.  Shall post an answer with example.

Answer (score 0):

For a haiku sharing application I made I have something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var socket_id = socket.id;
    var client_ip = socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.handshake.address.address;
    clients.push(socket);
    console.info('New client connected (id=' + socket.id + ').');

    number_of_clients_connected++;
    console.log('[' + client_ip + '] connected, ' + number_of_clients_connected + ' total users online.');

    //when a socket is disconnected or closed, .on('disconnect') is fired
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        number_of_clients_connected--;
        console.log('[' + client_ip + '] disconnected, ' + number_of_clients_connected + ' total users online.');
        //on disconnect, remove from clients array
        var index = clients.indexOf(socket);
        if (index != -1) {
            clients.splice(index, 1);
            //console.info('Client gone (id=' + socket.id + ').');
        }
    });
```

So it keeps an array of clients and when certain messages need relaying you can specify the client socket ID...

```
//reads from latest_haikus_cache and sends them
socket.on('request_haiku_cache', function() {
    latest_haikus_cache.forEach(function(a_latest_haiku) {
        clients[clients.indexOf(socket)].emit('load_haiku_from_cache', a_latest_haiku);
    });
});
```

Comment: And, how does this answer the question?

Comment: offers a different approach.  the asker wants to send messages to specific clients, and rooms -- although a nice idea in socket.io -- are not what i ended up using

Answer (score 0):

The server is allowed to broadcast to any room so you can support letting a client ask the server to send to a room without that client being in the room.  It really depends upon what you want to do.

So, if you want your server to have this code that lets any client send a message to any room of their choosing:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('new msg from client', function(roomId, msg){
    io.to(roomId).emit('new msg from server', msg);
  });
});
```

Then, you can indeed do that and it will work.  Whether it's appropriate or not is entirely up to your application and whether you want any client to be able broadcast to any room that it has the name of.

> But will this work?

Yes, it will work.

> Shouldn't I join the room with socket.join(...) before I can do this?

There is no need to have the client join the room unless it wants to receive messages for that room.  You don't have be in the room in order to ask the server to send to that room if that's how you want to do it.  So, all this is entirely up to your application and what is appropriate.

> I have a route /rooms/:roomId.
>
> Is it possible to make the sockets being sent between the server and
>   the client only hits the specific room?

I could not figure out what this part of your question means.  If you care to explain further, I will try to help with this part too.

Comment: When a client enters a room on route `/rooms/:roomId`, I retrieve all the messages belonging to this `roomId` from the database.. When the client is still at this URL without updating the page, I want it to retrieve new messages using `socket.io`. But I only want the client to retrieve the messages specifically sent to this room (and not all the other rooms). So on the client, I am also attaching the `roomId` when I am emitting. Now I want to tell the server to only emit the new messages to those clients who are currently in the room to which the `roomId` belongs.

Comment: @Jamgreen - If you send the desired room ID with your client `.emit()`, then the server will receive that argument and can use it to know which room to get the messages from as it sounds like you know that.  What is it you need help with?

Comment: When I emit from the server to the clients, I am using `io.sockets.emit('hi clients from the server');` which is received by ALL clients. I want ONLY the clients in a given `roomId` to receive the message from the server.. So I want to be able to use `io.to('some room id').sockets.emit('hi clients in this room from the server');` to send this message to only those clients connected on the route `/rooms/:roomId`.

Comment: Use `socket.emit()` to send only to the `socket` that you just received a message from.

Comment: But I want to send to all the sockets connected to the url (with the specific room id).

Comment: @Jamgreen - Then, have the server put those sockets into a room by that name when they connect and announce that's the room they want to be in.  Then broadcast to that room from the server and it will send to every connection in that room.  That's how you use rooms with socket.io.  That's what they are for.  Your question does not clearly state this is what you're trying to do.